# How to change Navigation group item size

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I have 2 groups of menu items in a navigation drawer. Here is my menu.xml file.

```html
<group
        android:id="@+id/pages"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/mHomePage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
            android:title="@string/home" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/mAboutFragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
            android:title="@string/about_us" />

        ...
    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/actions"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">

        <item android:id="@+id/mActionShare"
            android:title="@string/share_the_app"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"/>

        ...
    </group>
```

It so happens that the text of the 2nd group is bigger than the first. I want to specifically make the text size of the 2nd group smaller.
How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your needs, you need to use `SpannableString`

```
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getTitle());
    spannableString.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.TextStyle), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setTitle(spannableString);
```

As you can see `getItem` method needs a menu item index :

- the index of item **HomePage** is 0
- the index of item **AboutFragment** is 1
- the index of item **ActionShare** is 2

Create a style and  name it ***TextStyle*** :

```
 <style name="TextStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item> //SPECIFY YOUR TEXT SIZE
 </style>
```